# how to post array of values in jquery-ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

How to post array of values in jquery-ajax?

```
<input type='text' name='mynameinputs[]'>
<textarea id='mydescription' name='mydescriptioninputs[]'></textarea>
<input type='text' name='myquantityinputs[]'>

<input type='text' name='mynameinputs[]'>
<textarea id='mydescription' name='mydescriptioninputs[]'></textarea>
<input type='text' name='myquantityinputs[]'>

<input type='text' name='mynameinputs[]'>
<textarea id='mydescription' name='mydescriptioninputs[]'></textarea>
<input type='text' name='myquantityinputs[]'>

$.post(url,{''}, function(data){}
```

How to get the values of each and post it to a php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method on the containing form:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#if_of_the_form').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

`$('#if_of_the_form').serialize()` will format the values as if it was a normal form submit - using [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).

Comment: thanks @Darin for the quick answer. How to catch those values though in foo.php?

Comment: The same way you would have caught them if you wasn't using any javascript at all but a standard form submission. I am not a PHP guy so cannot tell you, but I guess you will have to use `$_POST` or something.

Comment: Yepp, `$_POST['element_name'];` +1